# Showing that a points projection onto a plane and a line in the plane form a line perpendicular to the line

Tags: geometry

Show that if $p\in{\mathbb{R^3}}$ is a point outside a plane $Π$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, if $p′$ is its orthogonal projection on $Π$ and if $p′′$ is its orthogonal projection onto a line $L$ contained in $Π$, then the line $\overline{p′p'′}$ is perpendicular to $L$.

Intuitively this makes sense. Its like you're rotating around The line $L$ of angle $\angle{pp''p'}$ and showing that after the rotation $\overline{p'p''}$ lies in/on $\overline{p''p}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L\parallel \vec{r}$

$\vec{pp'}$ is normal to $\Pi$ and hence $\vec{pp'}\cdot \vec{r}=0$.

$\vec{p'p''}\cdot\vec{r}=(\vec{pp''}-\vec{pp'})\cdot\vec{r} =\vec{pp''}\cdot\vec{r}=0$.